# Running a whole scenario before another scenario

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-jvm

I'm not able to figure out how to run a whole scenario before an other scenario, so that my test are not dependant on eachother.

I have this imaginary scenarios.

Scenario A
Given I have something
When I sumbit some data
I should see it on my webpage

Scenario B
Given **SCENARIO A**
When I delete the data
I should not see it on my webpage

When I run this scenario case, the software does not recognize **Scenario A** in scenario B, and ask me to create the step, like this...

You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

`@Given("^Registrere formue og inntekt$")`
`public void registrere_formue_og_inntekt() throws Throwable {`
`// Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions`
`throw new PendingException();`
`}`

Comment: Can you clarify your question,? Because, although you say "so that my tests are not dependant", what you are asking will make tests obviously dependant on each other.

Comment: I want Scenario B, to run all steps that Scenario A does, but I do not want to copy all 3 steps in Scenari A, into B... I want only to refer to A.  And to make Scenario B dependant on A, would be to do something like this:  Scenario B  When I delete the data  I should not see it on my webpage

Answer (score 4):

You could either:

- Use a `Background` to group all the steps that need to be executed before the different scenarii:

```
Background:
Given I have something
When I submit some data
Then I should see it on my webpage 

Scenario: B
When I delete the data
Then I should not see it on my webpage
```

- Group them as part of a step definition:

```
@Given("^Scenario A")
public void scenario_A() {
    I_have_something();
    I_submit_some_data();
    I_should_see_it_on_my_page();
}
```

which you can then use like this:

```
Given Scenario A
When I delete the data
Then I should not see it on my webpage
```

Using this technique, you usually observe that some actions are constantly reused, and you may want to factor them out so that they can be reused across different step definitions; at that point, the Page Object pattern comes very handy.

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber scenarios are supposed to be independent. A lot of work is done assuming and ensuring that independence. Trying to go against will be an obstacle course.

Having said that, you could create your custom implementation of the `Cucumber` JUnit runner. Having this custom implementation, and by looking at the source of the original runner, you can expose / wrap / change the internals to allow what you want. For example with the following runner:

```java
public class MyCucumber extends Cucumber {

    private static Runtime runtime;
    private static JUnitReporter reporter;
    private static List<CucumberFeature> features;

    public MyCucumber(Class<?> clazz) throws InitializationError, IOException {
        super(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    protected Runtime createRuntime(ResourceLoader resourceLoader,
            ClassLoader classLoader, RuntimeOptions runtimeOptions)
            throws InitializationError, IOException {
        this.runtime = super.createRuntime(resourceLoader, classLoader, runtimeOptions);
        this.reporter = new JUnitReporter(runtimeOptions.reporter(classLoader), runtimeOptions.formatter(classLoader), runtimeOptions.isStrict());
        this.features = runtimeOptions.cucumberFeatures(resourceLoader);

        return this.runtime;
    }

    public static void runScenario(String name) throws Exception {
        new ExecutionUnitRunner(runtime, getScenario(name), reporter).run(new RunNotifier());
    }

    private static CucumberScenario getScenario(String name) {
        for (CucumberFeature feature : features) {
            for (CucumberTagStatement element : feature.getFeatureElements()) {
                if (! (element instanceof CucumberScenario)) {
                    continue;
                }

                CucumberScenario scenario = (CucumberScenario) element;
                if (! name.equals(scenario.getGherkinModel().getName())) {
                    continue;
                }

                return scenario;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

You can setup your test suite with:

```java
@RunWith(MyCucumber.class)
public class MyTest {
}
```

And create a step definition like:

```java
@Given("^I first run scenario (.*)$")
public void i_first_run_scenario(String name) throws Throwable {
    MyCucumber.runScenario(name);
}
```

It is a fragile customization (can break easily with new versions of `cucumber-junit`) but it should work.